# Kivy Framework - Most pythonic solution with TextInput/Label Updating?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

I've been working with Kivy and Python 3 and I've run across a problem. I have 2 widgets in a BoxLayout, one a TextInput widget and one a Label widget. When some text is entered into the TextInput widget and the enter key is pressed, I would like `Label.text` to update to reflect `TextInput.text`.

I've put together a solution that works. Here is the code (question after the break):

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

class TexttestApp(App):
    def on_enter(self,textin):
        self.lab.text = textin.text #is this incorrect?

    def build(self):
        window = BoxLayout()
        self.lab = Label(text="Inital Label") #is this incorrect?
        text = TextInput(multiline=False)
        text.bind(on_text_validate=self.on_enter)
        window.add_widget(text)
        window.add_widget(self.lab) 
        return window
```

My questions are as follows: 
**Is assigning the Label widget to an instance variable a bad programming practice? From a software engineering point of view, is this bad/confusing? Or should I be assigning all of my widgets to the instance of the TexttestApp class?** (i.e. `self.text`, `self.window`, etc). The code right now looks disorganized to me, but I can't figure out another way of solving the problem.

Thanks in advance. This is my first attempt at using `bind()` to attach a function to a keyboard event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This all looks fine to me. I suppose in principle I could nitpick stuff, but there's really nothing very important in such a small code snippet, since you aren't doing anything really wrong. The stuff you comment is fine, in general terms, and there's no rule against storing stuff as attributes of your app although there may be better or more convenient alternatives (as below).

From a kivy point of view, the biggest thing is probably...use kv language! In this case, you could have a file texttest.kv with

```
BoxLayout:
    TextInput:
        multiline: False
        on_text_validate: the_label.text = self.text
    Label:
        id: the_label
        text: "Initial Label"
```

This would replace both methods of your app class. It's quite similar to your example in length, since it's very simple, but I'd say its already a little clearer - and kv rapidly becomes *much* clearer and less verbose as things become more complicated, since it takes care of a lot of bindings automatically.

This example happens to also avoid binding to your own function to change the label text, since it can all be done in a line of kv, but your way isn't wrong and it might still be appropriate to call a method or function in the python file if the task is more complex.